# что означает знак -> в ООП?

Tags: ооп, php

Первый раз сталкиваюсь с ООП, везде вижу `->` , что это за знак присваивания или добавления ? Гуглил, не нашел ответа. И еще: `$this` - означет так как и jQuеry?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Оператор малая стрелка `->` предназначен в PHP для работы с объектами при объектно-ориентированном программировании - то есть если у вас есть класс `someclass` и создан объект `$obj=new someclass` то обращаться к его полям и методам можно как раз с помощью оператора `$obj->field`

Если вдаваться в саму работу данного оператора то он может как реально вывызвать методы и считывать/изменять свойства объекта - так и работать за счет функции-перенаправления которая будет выполняться определенные дейтсвия с данными справа от оператора `->`

Если приводить аналогию с другими языками программирования, то этот оператор похож на оператор "ТОЧКУ" в языках C/C++/C#/Java/JS и некоторых других - а его синтаксис и семантика взяты из языка Perl

Comment: понятно))) Кнопка наградить опасная штука:)))))